# ARM Processor or FPGA to video signal processing?

Tags: fpga, arm, linux, signal-processing, imageprocessing

I want to design a PCB where a video camera will take images and they will be shown in a display HD. So I have several questions in order to achieve it: I would like to know what is the best option for video signal processing, use a FPGA or a ARM processor? In the case that I use a ARM processor, I will have to install in the processor an OS like Linux? and how I load the firmware in this processor? 
Thanks in advance Regards
 Javi

Comment: What is it you want to do that pretty much any tablet computer can't do?

Comment: I know that there are a lot of development boards which can do it but I need to design something similar. The first step is if use a ARM processor or a FPGA. What is the best option or what is more tipycal to use?

Answer (score 2):

The reason Dave asked you what you want to do is because what path you pick will depend on your goal.

- What will the interface be to your camera?  HDMI, Composite, YUV,
  directly to an image sensor etc?
- What frame rate and resolution do you want to work with?
- Do you want to process every frame?
- What are you going to do with the video data something simple?  Something complex?
- Is this just a school project, work project, proof of concept?  Can you afford a suitable FPGA in your final cost?  How about a suitable FPGA development board?
- What's your skill level in FPGA design vs embedded software?

You can do a design any number of ways but you have to consider all of the tradeoffs before you make a decision.  There are small fpgas, large expensive ones, generic ARM processors, video processing specific processors (some that you'll only get if you are a large volume customer).

Based only on the limited information you supplied I would say if your budget and ammount of processing per frame rate are low take a look at some arm processors.  You might even consider a lower cost FPGA like a lattice, or low end spartan or MAX.

If your frame rate and processing needs are high, and final cost is not an issue take a look at a higher end FPGA as a solution.

If your frame rate and processing needs are high, and final cost is an issue, design an ASIC :)

Comment: Hi,the camera interface will be 4 line MIPI.The camera frame rate is 60fps and the resolution > 8 megapixel. I want to show the video image taken by the camera in a display HD. Not too complex. It is a work project. We can afford everything if that is the best option, the thing is what is the best option, ARM, FPGA so on. I know the basic in FPGAs and I worked once with the Pandaboard so that I am almost a beginner in embedded software. So I want to know also what would be the most easy solution. Regards

Comment: I would take some time to look at lattices video solutions.  They have a lot of available in house and 3rd party video ip and are very big in the sensor/mipi interface world.   I think you could find mipi ip, video out ip and just hook them up with your code.   http://www.latticesemi.com/Solutions/SolutionCategories/MIPIInterfaces.

Comment: You could use the other guys too but their mipi ips are expensive :)

Comment: So I see that lattice semiconductor develop FPGAs. Is it better use a FPGA then?. Even if I use a FPGA,would it be necessary to use a processor also?. Program a FPGA would be easier than in a ARM Procesor for a beginner? I think that in the majority of the embedded systems, a ARM processor is used right?

Comment: There is no easier, only try and learn :)  Yes ARM is a popular but not the only Processor in use by any means.  Look if your more comfortable with C than Verilog go with an ARM.  If you can handle Verilog go with FPGA.  For your limited application I'd think you won't need a frame buffer in the FPGA so it's just simple format conversion and data moving.  With a processor you'll need all the overhead that comes with it, DDR, OS, probably writing a driver.   But this getting to be more opinion than fact.  Really the choice is up to you.

Comment: With either path, I'd recommend you find either an ARM or FPGA reference design that is close to what you want to do and start there.

Comment: ok, but with a FPGA is possible to use Verilog or VHDL right?

Comment: Yes sorry I just said verilog, vhdl is fine too.

Comment: So do you know any motherboard which is able to do these similar task?. Like take video data from a camera and visualize them in a display HD connected in the board. So in this way I could take a look in the schematic to have an idea

Comment: Maybe the HDR-60 http://www.latticesemi.com/hdr60

Comment: ok thanks. And if I use a FPGA, I would need also a processor? or just with the FPGA is enough to process the video?

Comment: To do what you described take video from camera, and output it to a display you don't need a processor.  However you might consider adding a small processor for house keeping and control.  Maybe you will want to make adjustments to the camera or image sensor, or change some settings inside your modules for example.  That's doable in an FPGA but maybe easier with a little side processor.  Now you can put a processor inside an FPGA, or Xilinx and Altera make FPGAs with ARM cores already inside that connect directly to the FPGA fabric.

Comment: Ok and when the FPGA also contain a processor. How both can work at the same time sharing ports and buses?. Since the way of working of a FPGA is by digital blocks and processors run sequentially. I mean they run different each other